# Tools for measuring coupling and cohesion

Tags: coupling, cohesion

Do you know of any tools that help us measure coupling and cohesion in the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [static code analisys tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis)

Depending on the language you use you can use Tools to get several information from static analisys.
Personally I use free tool [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) to collect information such as Number of calls and Methods/Class that shows you something related to coupling and cohesion.

You can use Quality Check Tools to (FxCop, Checkstyle, PMD, etc.).

Comment: Source Monitor does not measure coupling or cohesion, as of what I know